# Как лишний раз не рендерить интерфейс в react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, jsx

Начал изучать react и дошел до получения данных из дб, и столкнулся с не понятием как правильно это реализовать, я захотел сделать hooks который бы принимал ссылку обрабатывал и отдавал ответ, в компонент где был вызван, но столкнулся с проблемой что мой интерфейс рендерится 2 раза, и ладно тут у меня просто форма логина, но если бы там была сложная форма, и каждый раз её рендорит слишком, хотя например данный запрос не делал бы ничего, просто проверял какую-то информацию например. Как мне правильно реализовать получения данных из моей дб.

React login.jsx COMPONENT

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import SVGLogo from '../compontents/UI/SVGLogo';
import Matrix from '../compontents/UI/Matrix';
import Square from '../compontents/UI/Square';
import LoginForm from '../compontents/form/LoginForm';
import useFetchData from '../hooks/useFetchData';

const Login = () => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const [rows, cols] = [6, 6];

    const { data, error, loading, fetchData } = useFetchData();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }, [data]);

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        fetchData('login.php');
    }, [fetchData]);

    console.log(1);

    return (
        <div style={{ minHeight: '100dvh' }} className='flex w-full justify-center items-center overflow-hidden p-2'>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Data</button>
            <div className="text-[var(--card-main-text)] max-w-sm">
                <div className='login-wrapper relative'>
                    <div className="graphics-el">
                        <Matrix
                            size='6px'
                            gap='1.25rem'
                            rows={rows}
                            cols={cols}
                            className="fill-matrix absolute -top-16 -right-16 -z-20"
                        />

                        <Matrix
                            size='6px'
                            gap='1.25rem'
                            rows={rows}
                            cols={cols}
                            className="grid fill-matrix absolute -bottom-14 -left-14 -z-20 bg-indigo-900/5 p-5 rounded-xl"
                        />

                        <Square
                            className='w-52 h-52 absolute -bottom-28 left-12 -z-10 rounded-lg border-[0.15rem] border-gray-50'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ '--delay': '30ms' }} className="startAnimate bg-[var(--card-bg)] p-6 myShadow rounded-md">
                        <div className="form_header">
                            <div className="logo flex gap-2 items-center">
                                <SVGLogo
                                    className="w-20 h-20 fill-[var(--SVGLogo)] stroke-[var(--SVGLogo)] stroke-[5px]" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                />
                                <div
                                    className="logo-title font-medium text-2xl"
                                >Database</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="info">
                                <div className="info-title text-xl font-medium">
                                    Welcome to the database!
                                </div>
                                <div className="sub-title text-base text-[var(--card-main-text-var1)] font-normal">
                                    Please sign-in to your account to use the database.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <LoginForm
                            username={username}
                            password={password}
                            setUsername={setUsername}
                            setPassword={setPassword}
                        />
                        <div className="form_footer">
                            <div className="info text-base text-[var(--card-main-text-var1)] font-light">
                                {console.log(2)}
                                If you don't have an account/forgot your password - please contact the system administrator: <b className='font-medium'>***</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Hoks useFetchData.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost/my-app/src/API/ajax/';

const useFetchData = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = async (initialUrl) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${serverUrl}${initialUrl}`);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { data, error, loading, fetchData };
};

export default useFetchData;
```

В начале есть console.log(1);
И в конце в компоненте console.log(2);

И при нажатие на кнопку `<button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Data</button>`
Рендор происходит 2 раза. А хотелось бы чтобы не было рендора, так как данный запрос к примеру не должен ничего менять. Буду благодарень если поможете понять как правильно делать запросы.

Comment: Установка компонент - первый рендер. Жмяк по кнопке, вызов хука, данные в переменной data меняются, стоит эффект на data - вот второй рендер.

Comment: Почему появляется 2 рендора, это я понял. Знаю, вопрос состоит в другом как сделать правильно?

Comment: Ну в целом правильно сделано, только вот ненужные эффекты уберите. Ну и в целом, если хук не используется, то, наверное не стоит его использовать в компоненте. Лучше дергать внешнюю фукнцию, тогда она точна аффектить на компонент не будет.

Comment: Я сделал хук чтобы он был как шаблон, куда я передаю данные, и получаю ответ. Чтобы использовать их, это хук(шаблон) должен быть использован и в других файлах а useEffect я использовал чтобы получить данные, так как при запросе он асинхронный из-за чего в данные первый раз при нажатие я получаю null